# Offline mode highcharts in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, highcharts

I am trying to run dynamic Highcharts in offline mode in React Native. So, I am unable to change path of `highcharts.js` file locally. Please help me, how  to change the PATH `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js` to a local path.

Details:

- Create project in react native
- Add plugin: react-native-highcharts
- Change path: in `NODE_MODULES/REACT-NATIVE-HIGHCHARTS/REACT-NATIVE-HIGHCHARTS.JS` to a local path

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hey! I don't think the git tag is appropriate for this question 

Comment: Hi Amit Kumar, You want to modify the path in string in HTML format, so I think the path to `highcharts` should be related to the result file.

Comment: local Path is not working here. please suggest me how to use local path here.